# Prevent overlapping startdate and enddate php

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way to prevent overlapping start- and enddates in PHP?

I have the following records in my database:

[image: db records]

These are the dates available for selection in my form.
As you can see there's quite some overlapping dates. How do I prevent a date being picked that falls between another record.

If any other info is required, please ask.

Comment: Check before insert or constraint on table, you must validate on server side

Answer (score 0):

You should put a `TRIGGER` on your database table. Or you could add logic to your application before performing the `INSERT`. I would recommend the latter because it will be easier to provide feedback to the user of the system when overlapping dates are attempted.